# UserSecretsId prevents any deployment of F# ASP.NET Core app to Azure App Service

Tags: azure, f#, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy my F# ASP.NET Core app to Azure App Service. Unfortunately, each time I try to deploy, a `<UserSecretsId>` element is added to my project file, which as explained [in this article](https://medium.com/@dmytrol/making-asp-net-core-user-secrets-work-in-f-projects-9b04572d81f6) causes the build to fail with the following error:

`A function labeled with the 'EntryPointAttribute' attribute must be the last declaration in the last file in the compilation sequence`

The article explains why the error occurs and instructs to fix it by removing the element from the project file and instead adding the user secrets ID in an `AssemblyInfo.fs`. I have tried this and can then build manually, but each time I try to deploy, the deployment process still adds a `<UserSecretsId>` element with a new ID in my project file, causing the build to fail.

Is there any way I can publish an F# ASP.NET Core app to Azure App Service?

(Also reported on [Microsoft/visualfsharp#5549](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/5549))

Comment: Updated the question with the error message and a bit more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your .fsproj file to suppress the attribute generation.

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <GenerateUserSecretsAttribute>false</GenerateUserSecretsAttribute>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you want to use user secrets, you will manually need to add the UserSecrets assembly attribute.

```
module Your.Namespace.AssemblyInfo
open Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets
[<assembly: UserSecretsIdAttribute("Your UserSecretsId")>]
do()
```

Also, this workaround should be unnecessary in ASP.NET Core 2.2. See https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/pull/872